# How to get the content of `HttpInputOverHTTP` in Clojure Compojure/Ring project?

Tags: clojure

How  to get the content of an incoming `POST` http request's `:body #object[org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInputOverHTTP 0x42c3599b "HttpInputOverHTTP@42c3599b"]` in a Compojure/Ring project?

I know that this `:body` is composed of a part named `data` whose `MIME-type` is `text-plain` and another part named `excel` whose `MIME-type` is `application/excel`.

I `slurp`ed the content of `:body` and it shows:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parsing a binary stream manually would be difficult. Wrap your handler as follows:

`(wrap-multipart-params handler options)`

This middleware parses the body and populates `:params` parameters with parsed data as well.

See [ring.middleware.multipart-params](https://ring-clojure.github.io/ring/ring.middleware.multipart-params.html) documentation for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing it in Reitit, what fixed for me was to change the order of the middlewares so the `exception-middleware` is after the `multipart/multipart-middleware`.

```clj
:middleware [;; multipart
             multipart/multipart-middleware
             ;; exception handling
             exception-middleware]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can find a basic example [in the Clojure Cookbook (O'Reilly)](https://github.com/clojure-cookbook/clojure-cookbook/blob/master/07_webapps/7-01_ringintroduction.asciidoc), which I highly recommend:

```
(ns ringtest
  (:require
    [ring.adapter.jetty :as jetty]
    clojure.pprint))

;; Echo (with pretty-print) the request received
(defn handler [request]
  {:status 200
   :headers {"content-type" "text/clojure"}
   :body (with-out-str (clojure.pprint/pprint request))})

(defn -main []
  ;; Run the server on port 3000
  (jetty/run-jetty handler {:port 3000}))
```

Comment: This is irrelevant and doesn't solve the problem. See the accepted answer.